# TinyMCE Editor -How to integrate the customization scrollbar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce

I need to integrate the custom scroll bar to TinyMCE Editor.Can you please guid me how to integrate it.

Url:http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: +1 difficult to  say, do you know that tinymce editor uses an iframe? i am not even sure this plugin supports this. if it deos you will have to load the necessary files intio the iframe head and define the elements of the editor body which shall get a scrollbar (i guess body in your case)

Comment: @Thariama:Yes I know that but as per our client requirment.

Comment: so you want to apply the scrollbar to elements inside the editor?

Comment: @Thariama:Yes..I need to remove the default scroll bar and  then after I need to integrate custom scroll bar.

Comment: Anybody..know that.How to integrate the custom scroll bar to tinymce editor?

Answer (score 0):

You get rid of the defaukt scollbar you may apply this css to the editor iframe (you might need to be more precise, otherwise you could remove scrollbars from other iframes as well)

```
iframe {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This is the necessay code to get css files into the tinymce editor iframe head

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
ed.dom.loadCSS( 'url_to_css_file');
```

Comment: Anybody know that how to integrat

Comment: as i said: 1. step: remove the scrollbar using overflow:hidden, 2. load all necessaryfiles into the editor iframe head

Comment: Have you integrated custom scrolling to tinymce editor?If yes so please send me the code.